# Go : doubly linked list implementing panic error

Tags: pointers, linked-list, go

Correction:

Link #1 http://play.golang.org/p/CKRNyWYF8X

Link #2 http://play.golang.org/p/oT2yKzFwep

From the first link,
I am sure that the panic error comes from this

```
func (A *DoublyLinkedList) AddHead(input_value interface{}) {
  temp_node := &Node{value: input_value, prev: nil, next: A.head}
  original_head_node := A.head
  original_head_node.prev = temp_node
  A.length++
}
```

But when I use this for doubly linked list, it panics little later. And still fails because this one below does not connect the original head with previous pointer.

```
  func (A *DoublyLinkedList) AddHead(input_value interface{}) {
     A.head = NewNode(input_value, nil, A.head)
     A.length++
  }
```

This is the one. This one has the similar problem.

```
  cannot assign to target_node.GetPrevNode().GetNextNode()
```

Does go not support pointer reference this way? I did fix this just assigning a new variable every time I need to get the pointer. But my first question on the top still does not compile.

In short, how do I connect the doubly linked list when adding a new element in Go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the properties inside the DoublyLinkedList. It seems to me, you are currently creating a reference to it in NewDoublyLinkedList() with 2 nil properties.

```
type DoublyLinkedList struct {
    head   *Node // nil
    tail   *Node // nil
    length int
}
```

And when doing this

```
original_head_node := A.head // A.head == nil
original_head_node.prev = temp_node // You are trying to access a property in nil
```

Comment: Yes right. I couldn't figure out how to initialize the nil pointers at first before I need to access.

Comment: What do you mean by initialize inside? I did it knowing that it's not gonna work assigning to nil. But can't think of any way to do it correctly.

Comment: Look at the first line in AddHead method. The way you initialize the Node struct should give you the answer.

Comment: A.head = NewNode(input_value, nil, A.head). Did you mean this? This works only for singly linked list. I need to handle the prev node of the original head node.